# Access API on remote machine via Apache

Tags: windows, apache

I have an API running locally on http://127.0.0.1:81, and this machine is somewhere in the network, and has Apache 2.4 installed. This is Windows Server OS

I would like to access the API from my local computer (on same company network?), but don't understand these concepts fully yet.

Here's what I've done

`hosts`

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      my-api.com
```

`httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
Listen 10.75.32.157:81
# Listen 127.0.0.1:81
<VirtualHost 192.18.13.207:81>
   DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/my-api"
   ServerName my-api.com
   ServerAlias www.my-api.com
   ErrorLog "logs/my-api-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/my-api-access.log" common

   <Directory "${SRVROOT}/my-api">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
      # Order allow,deny
      # Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I visit http://127.0.0.1:81 on the remote computer, I can access my API.

But If I visit http://192.18.13.207:81 from my local computer, it's showing me the files in the API directory. But I am hoping I will access the API.

Any ideas how to achieve this? TIA